# Grid Layout with ImageButton width and height

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I am trying to create a Grid Layout with 2 Columns and 3 Rows. I will use ImageButtons for the grid, so that there's 6 images on the screen, each with the same size. When I add the background to the ImageButton, the button fills the whole screen. Should I add Width and Height properties to fix this? Can anyone help me?

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/team_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnCount="2"
    android:rowCount="3"
    >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/alexandre"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background=""
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:src="@drawable/alexandre"/>


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/barbara"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:src="@drawable/barbara"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/pedro"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:src="@drawable/goncalo"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton4"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:src="@drawable/pedro">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton5"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:src="@drawable/rafael"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ImageButton6"
        android:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:layout_columnWeight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill"
        android:background="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:src="@drawable/ricardo"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, Your question is a bit confusing because in your XML you have set the background of each ImageButton to white color which seems to have no effect but if you try setting different color for each one then it will set a different color accordingly. And, you can't have an empty value for background like in your first ImageButton. And, try to add some padding and margin for the ImageButton.I tried your code and it work's fine. Here's what I did.

```
<GridLayout android:id="@+id/team_grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="3"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/alexandre"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/barbara"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/pedro"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton4"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton5"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton6"
    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
    android:layout_gravity="fill"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"/>
```